# Why we use double % in Java or JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

When I checked a code yesterday, I've seen a line that was very strange for me.

There's a condition in JS code which is checking a string passed by parameter in this way `"%%unsubscribe%%"`. Please check the below line for reference

```js
if (link.attr("href").equalsIgnoreCase("%%unsubcriber%%"))
```

There's another reference in JSP page that is also very strange to me.

```html
<a style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); " href="%%unsubcriber%%">Unsubscribe</a>
```

Please help me out, why we use double `%` in Java?.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like template placeholders. If you look elsewhere in the code, you're likely to find somewhere that the code is taking a string containing that HTML and doing a `replace` or `replaceAll` on it, converting `%%unsubscriber%%` to someone's name/username.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in your Quora (?) post, and you neglected to post here, that line appears in a `<script>` tag, e.g.,

```
<script>
    if (link.attr("href").equalsIgnoreCase("%%unsubcriber%%"))
</script>
```

Your code is using a templating system. The `%%` is meaningless to JSP and will render as-is. Your JavaScript code loads the template by referencing the `<script>` tag and fills it in with data provided by JavaScript, using whatever templating system you're using.

Comment: Badass picture as avatar there ! :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios It's either that or I have to switch back to my mohawk one. Maybe I'll do that.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Switched anyway. More bad-assier.

Comment: @AndreaLigios There, *now* I switched. FEAR THE GEEK

Comment: Full NewYorker mode: activated ! O_o

Answer (score 1):

`%%unsubcriber%%` is a simple text marker in the text/html document generated from JSP. It could also be a part of custom HTML template. After the page is rendered, a custom HTML with values like that replaced with real values before writing the text/html to the response.